# Iterating through text and images within a Word Paragraph

Tags: vba, ms-word

I would like to iterate through "objects" within a paragraph of a Word document. Let's say this paragraph only contains characters and images.

I found a way to iterate through characters:

```
For Each lCharacter In pParagraph.Range.Characters
   ...
Next
```

I also found a way to iterate through images:

```
For Each lInlineShape In pParagraph.Range.InlineShapes
   ...
Next
```

Unfortunately theses loops do not allow me to know where the image(s) are located within the text.

What I want is to iterate on each "object" in order (either a character, an image or something else), find the kind of object it is and do some stuff on it accordingly.

Is there a way to do so?

(In fact, I found a clue: it seems that the first loop gives me a character "/" when there is an image... But I have no way to check whether that "/" means that there is an image there or if the text actually contains the character "/").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Word's object model wasn't really designed with this in mind. It can be done, but will be fairly slow. Working with the underlying Word Open XML would do this better and probably be a lot faster. However...

One possibility is to loop the characters and test `Range.InlineShapes.Count`. If a character is an `InlineShape` the count will be greater than 0 (it should be one):

```
Sub IsCharacterImage()
    Dim c As Word.Range

    For Each c In Selection.Characters
        If c.InlineShapes.Count > 0 Then
            Debug.Print "Is an image"
        Else
            Debug.Print "Is not an image"
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Another, albeit not terribly reliable approach, would be to get the `Start` or `End` property of the objects in the loops shown in the question and compare them in order to determine in which order the content appears.

The problem with this approach is that, if the Range has hidden characters, field codes or other non-visible "control characters" in the text these values could be inaccurate. So, on the whole, I'd tend towards the first approach...

```
Sub StartCharImage()
    Dim pParagraph As Word.Paragraph, lcharacter As Word.Range
    Dim linlineshape As Word.InlineShape
    Dim sCharStart As String, sImgStart As String
    Dim aCharStart As Variant, aImgStart As Variant

    Set pParagraph = ActiveDocument.paragraphs(1)
    For Each lcharacter In pParagraph.Range.Characters
       sCharStart = sCharStart & lcharacter.Start & ","
    Next
    sCharStart = Left(sCharStart, Len(sCharStart) - 1)
       Debug.Print sCharStart
    aCharStart = Split(sCharStart, ",")

    For Each linlineshape In pParagraph.Range.InlineShapes
        sImgStart = sImgStart & linlineshape.Range.Start & ","
    Next
    sImgStart = Left(sImgStart, Len(sImgStart) - 1)
    Debug.Print sImgStart
    aImgStart = Split(sImgStart, ",")
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to break these things down into separate inquiry by some category of object, either a Document or Paragraph within the document.

You can look for InlineShapes at the document level ...

```
Dim iShp As Word.InlineShape
For Each iShp In ActiveDocument.InlineShapes
    If iShp.Type = wdInlineShapePicture Then
        'do something
    End If
Next
```

Or, if you want to look at Paragraphs as you major group then something like this will work and you can include the look at characters in the range ...

```
Dim iShp As Word.InlineShape, oPara As Word.Paragraph
Dim chr As Variant
For Each oPara In ActiveDocument.Paragraphs
    For Each iShp In oPara.Range.InlineShapes
        If iShp.Type = wdInlineShapePicture Then
            'do something
        End If
    Next
    For Each chr In oPara.Range.Characters
        Debug.Print chr
    Next
Next
```

Comment: I have implemented the second solution, by first looking at Paragraphs, then Sentences, then Words, then Characters, but of course only when needed. It became much faster than looking at each Character systematically.